# Django create new instances of a different model using the submitted form data of a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Topic model which has a ManyToManyField to the Tag model. 
Similarly to stack overflow where you can submit new tags at the time of asking a question. I want to be able to create new tags when you create a topic.

A hacky solution from the top of my head.

```
Class TopicCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Topic
    template_name = 'blah'
    fields = [
       'blah'
    ]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        tags = self.request.POST.getlist(tags)
        for tag in tags:
            if not Tag.objects.filter(tag_string__iexact=tag):
                try:
                    new_tag = Tag.objects.create(tag_string=tag)
                except IntegrityError:
                    # stuff
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I'm new to Django and web frameworks in general, but this seems really hacky to me (if it even works). Given what I've read so far regarding FormSets and such, is there not a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Form and View are different. Which one is using here?

Comment: Sorry, Should have made it clear, I'm using the built in CreateView, without a form_class, specifying the model. Updated the example to reflect.

Comment: did you try your solution? Any problem?

Comment: No I haven't tried it yet. I have other dependencies that need implementing first, before this View will work. But even if it does, my question still stands. Is there a better way?

Comment: can you show your Topic model as well as Tag model?

Comment: Updated to include models

Comment: I think @Tsang-Yi Shen answer would do the job. Anyway I don't think this is possible through *django-signals*, because Tag won't get from signal

Answer (score 1):

Since the model code is not provided, I'm just guessing what you are thinking about:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    tags = self.request.POST.getlist('tags')
    existed_tags = Tag.objects \
        .filter(tag_string__iexact=tags) \
        .values_list('tag_string', flat=True)
    new_tags = set(tags) - set(existed_tags)

    for tag in new_tags:
        Tag.objects.create(tag_string=tag)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Perhaps your original codes can work but just need improvement (and thus I don't think it was 'hacky'). You put the `Tag` QuerySet within a for loop so the database will be hit in each time of iteration. To get all of the tag values from db first then compare the difference and do further work may be a better way.

Moreover, I think tag creation should not put in `form_valid` since this is a 'model procedure'. To override the `save()` method of `Topic` model or using Signal may be a better choice. Yet this is just my preference and you can still keep this unchanged.

Comment: This is what my thoughts were yes, this should not be in form_valid, but I assume I cannot define a save method without creating a form class? How would I use signals to achieve this? Can I use the pre_save() as a decorater perhaps? The only issue i see with this is, if there is an error how do I invalidate the form and feed it back to the user, as at the save stage the form has already been validated no?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I make an over-assumption here. I just think it shall trigger `Topic.save()` after sending the form since you use a `CreateView` with `model=Topic`. then your can override the `save()` method or trigger 'pre_save` signal via `Topic` saving. If that is not the case, please kindly ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a more acceptable solution keeping the model creation out of the `View()` and in the `Form()`, as defining `form_class` is still possible with the `CreateView()`.
I took inspiration from how stack overflow handles tags, in that they accept a string and split each tag on `'+'`.

There may be a way to further improve this but `FormSets` did not seem like viable option in this instance.

```
Class TopicCreateForm(forms.ModelForm)
    submitted_tags = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    class Meta:
        model = Blah
        fields = ['blah']

    def clean_submitted_tags(self):
        tags = self.cleaned_data.get(
            'submitted_tags').split("+")

        # validation here

        return tags

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # get author from form instance
        author = self.instance.author 

        tags = self.cleaned_data['submitted_tags']
        existing_tags = Tag.objects.values_list(
            'tag_string', flat=True)

        for tag in [t for t in tags if t not in existing_tags]:
            new_tag = Tag.objects.create(
                tag_string=tag,
                created_by=author)

        new_tags = Tag.objects.filter(tag_string__in=tags)
        new_tag_uuids = [t.pk for t in new_tags]

        self.cleaned_data['tags'] = new_tag_uuids

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```